# Vue Draggable to and from

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, rubaxa-sortable

I have an array of objects. Each object contains an array of objects.

eg:

```
wishlists: [
    {
        name: 'wishlist 1',
        id: '123',
        items: [
            {
                image: "foobar.jpg",
                name: "warlock",
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                image: "foobar1.jpg",
                name: "warlock1",
                quantity: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'wishlist 2',
        id: '1422',
        items: [
            {
                image: "foobar.jpg",
                name: "warlock",
                quantity: 7
            },
            {
                image: "foobar1.jpg",
                name: "warlock1",
                quantity: 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm using vue draggable within a loop to render each lists.

```
 <div v-for="(list, index) in wishlists">
     <draggable v-model="list.items" :key="list._id" :options="{group:'wishes'}" class="dropZone" @change="checkMove">
</div>
```

My checkMove method simply logs the change event.

```
{added: {…}}
added:
element:
image: "foobar.jpg"
name: "Warlock"
quantity: 1
 ...
newIndex: 0
 ...
{removed: {…}}
removed: {element: {…}, oldIndex: 0}
 ...
{moved: {…}}
moved: {element: {…}, oldIndex: 1, newIndex: 0}
```

I need to trigger a POST upon each action. I don't want to send the entire root wishlists array back to the server on every event, as that would be nuts! I only need to POST what has changed.

With the @change event, I see I am able to get the object that has been moved - along with its oldIndex position (in the old list), and its newIndex position (in the new list). However, I am not told anything about the lists. I need to know which list it came from, and which list it landed on.

Is there any way to obtain this information? If I can get the ID of the wishlist along with the newIndex and oldIndex etc - then I can post this info back to the server, and update the db...

I've played with every event, and it doesn't look like any give any information about the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<draggable v-model="list.items" :key="list._id" :options="{group:'wishes'}" ... @end="checkMove">
```

@end gives me to list, from list, oldIndex, newIndex... ugghhh... I was certain I tried it. It doesn't give me the item - but I have the index, so i just use that to reference by index.